# How to estimate the mutual information

Tags: probability, statistics

I have two discrete non-negative random variables $X$ and $Y$. I know $X$ is the number of heads you get by tossing $n$ unbiased coins and I know $Y$ is in the range $0,\dots n$.  I can sample from both (by computer) and I would like to estimate the mutual information $I(X;Y) = H(X) - H(X|Y)$ from the samples that I get.  In my case $n$ is only about $100$ and I can take tens of thousands of samples at least.

How can you do this?

Comment: What is the distribution of $Y$?

Comment: @brd I don't have an explicit form for it but I can sample from it by computer fairly quickly.

Comment: Your question implies that $X$ and $Y$ are independent (is that so?). In that case, $H(X|Y)=H(X)$.

Comment: @Stelios  The random variables are not independent. I didn't mean to imply they were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $H(X)$, it seems there's a [known closed form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution):

$$ \frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi e np(1-p)) + O(1/n) $$

where $p=0.5$ in your case and $n$ is the number of trials

By the Weak Asymptotic Equipartition Property (see, e.g. Yeung - Information Theory and Network Coding, Theorem 5.1, or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_equipartition_property)), the "empirical" entropy converges in probability to the true entropy.  Mathematically,

$$ -\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N\log p(X_k) \rightarrow H(X) ~\text{in probability}$$

where $X_k$ are i.i.d. with distribution $p(X)$ and $N$ is the number of "samples" you take empirically.  The joint AEP says the same about jointly distributed RVs and their joint entropy.  In this way, you should be able to derive an estimate of $H(X|Y)$ with a large number of samples $N$ (10,000 seems pretty large, so maybe it will converge even faster than that).  If the inverse $n$ order of growth from $H(X)$ is troublesome to you, you can do the same for $H(X)$.